# wp_dequeue_style in Genesis framework not working

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I wish to clean my code from duplicate css in my child genesis theme.
Some plugins use the same library with different version like font-awesome.

If you see html code here www.cartomanziadivinazione.it you can see:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css' href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=1.3.9' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I wish to delete this row and I wrote this in function theme

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cleaning_seo');

function cleaning_seo() { 
wp_dequeue_style( 'fontawesome-css' );
wp_deregister_style( 'fontawesome-css' ); 
}
```

but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

According to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script):

> Remove an enqueued script.
>
> To be dequeued, the script must have been enqueued. Attempting to
>   dequeue a script before the script is enqueued will have no effect.

So, a possibility is you are trying to dequeue the script before it queued.

To make sure that you are using this function in the right place; try increasing the execution order:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cleaning_seo', 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late, but maybe this answer will help others.

The handle has to be `fontawesome`, not `fontawesome-css`:

```
wp_dequeue_style( 'fontawesome' );
wp_deregister_style( 'fontawesome' );
```

The `-css` is added to the handle by WordPress (in the case of `text/javascript` `-js` is added).